# NopCommerce New function for Posting Resources and Authentication

Tags: nopcommerce

i want to access resources through Android using Web Api but first i want to authenticate user , and then access resources . Can anyone guide me on how  to do that ?

Comment: What do you mean with resources? Products or just images and static files?

Comment: products, orders, categories etc.

Comment: nopCommerce does not support it by default. You have to use a plugin to enable access using web api. Maybe the 7Spikes api plugin could be something for you.